# redirect after ok is pressed in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the following code:

```
    if(isSolved()){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("You solved the puzzle! Congratulations!")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Thanks.",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                   @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity (intent);
                    }
                });
    }
```

It's a puzzle and when the puzzle it resolved it shows the above message:"Congrats! you finished the game!". But when I press ok it doesn't do anything. I would want after pressing ok to redirect to another page. i'm using java with eclipse.

Comment: I've updated the answer but now it gives me an error on startActivity(intent); ...

Comment: What error do you get? You can find it in the logcat

Comment: it says to create method startActivity (intent);

Comment: May be your code is in a fragment. `startActivity()` method is in Context class, so you need to get a context, e.g. `getActivity().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: i've put context.startActivity() but it doesn't do anything. it doesn't show the allert message nor redirect

Comment: It's another question already. Ask new question, please. Nobody will answer in the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add OnClickListener to the PositiveButton and handle your redirect in onclick:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Thanks.", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //Do your redirect here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alert.setButton("Okay", listener);`
And in your listener catch the click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.setMessage("Congrats! you finished the game!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Thanks.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
```

[AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))